# Finding the list of changesets a particular file has been modified in

Tags: mercurial

I want to update my repository to the second last time a particular file was modified. How does one list the changesets where a particular file was modified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `log` command and set custom style:

```
$ hg log --template "{node}\n" file
```

Sample output of hashes (like git):

```
7e96adf02fe2d633443c327a66cb34d9806b6e52
5d8f310f025a7e92a06bf0ace9e3077e8c02ea24
a987682208a9a04cb546d5bc3de38eba115a8494
69f73525ecbad1479356b488d1c15796a8f15176
```

Or revisions, like in svn:

```
$ hg log --template "{rev}\n" file

271
256
254
253
```

Or like hg:

```
$ hg log --template "{rev}:{node}\n" file 

271:7e96adf02fe2d633443c327a66cb34d9806b6e52
256:5d8f310f025a7e92a06bf0ace9e3077e8c02ea24
254:a987682208a9a04cb546d5bc3de38eba115a8494
253:69f73525ecbad1479356b488d1c15796a8f15176
```

Comment: Specifying a custom style is probably even overkill in this particular case :).

Comment: @LaurensHolst Heh, I was assuming he just wanted a list of changesets or revisions as `hg log` by default also gives commit message, etc